# Plugging both ATX 12V (4+4pin) and EPS 12V (8pin) to x570 master

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I would like to plug the [Thermaltake 1500](https://www.thermaltake.com/toughpower-1500w-gold.html) on the x570 Master

From PSU Manual:

[image: PSU Thermaltake 1500]

Semi-modular PSU with both cables

[image]

[image]

Motherboard below

[image]

[image]
[image]

[Link to Manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_x570-aorus-master_1102_e.pdf)

Can I plug both EPS12V and ATX12V into the motherboard at the same time? Is there any difference between those plugs?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to, if you want your system to boot.

eg. [Tom's Hardware](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/what-is-eps12v.217277/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_%28computer%29)